How to find the difference between the lowest and highest values of a column with NA
How can I calculate the difference between the largest and smallest value row-wise, for each column when there are plenty of NA?
Let's assume this is my data:
   a   b   c  d   e
A  1   NA  3  NA  NA
B  0   NA  6  NA  2
C  3   2   1  NA  3
C  NA  NA  3  NA  0

For each column, I want to find the difference between the row with the highest value and the row with the lowest value - the result should look like this:
3 0 5 NA 3

I have hundreds of columns to analyse so I need a code that is easy to handle (eg: I won't need to manually input the column names).
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

An approach using sapply. Checking for all-NA values with ifelse to prevent -Inf results from min/max
sapply(df, \(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(x, na.rm=T) - min(x, na.rm=T)))
 a  b  c  d  e 
 3  0  5 NA  3 

Data
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 0L, 3L, NA), b = c(NA, NA, 2L, NA), 
    c = c(3L, 6L, 1L, 3L), d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), e = c(NA, 2L, 
    3L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))


a <- matrix(c(1,   NA,  3,  NA,  NA, 0,   NA,  6,  NA , 2, 3 ,  2 ,  1 , NA,  3, NA , NA,  3  ,NA,  0), nrow=4, ncol=5, byrow=T)
apply(a, 1, function(x) max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T)) # difference by row
apply(a, 2, function(x) max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T)) # difference by column

You may see -inf in cases where a difference cannot be calculated. To change this behavior, use code below:
apply(a, 1, function(x) ifelse(max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T) == -Inf, NA, max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T))) # difference by row
apply(a, 2, function(x) ifelse(max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T) == -Inf, NA, max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T))) # difference by column

